# How do I execute a line of code repeatedly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a stamina bar in my game and have had it all hooked up, though the tutorial I followed for it was specifyed for a burst of stamina used. I was hoping I would be able to slowly deminish it until there is none left. I tried to apply a while loop hooked up to a coroutine though it freezes unity. I just want way to lose stamina consistantly while a button is held. Its unable to be put under the void update because the code to check if shift is activated only plays it once. I activate the script by using "stamina.instance.UseStamina(5);". Heres the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class stamina : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Slider staminabar;
    private int maxstamina = 100;
    private int currentstamina;
    public static stamina instance;
    private WaitForSeconds regenTick = new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    private Coroutine regen;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentstamina = maxstamina;
        staminabar.maxValue = maxstamina;
        staminabar.value = maxstamina;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void UseStamina(int amount)
    {
        if (currentstamina - amount >= 0)
        {
            currentstamina -= amount;
            staminabar.value = currentstamina;

            if (regen != null)
                StopCoroutine(regen);

            regen = StartCoroutine(regenstamina());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("out of stamina!");
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator regenstamina()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        while (currentstamina < maxstamina)
        {
            currentstamina += maxstamina / 100;
            staminabar.value = currentstamina;
            yield return regenTick;
        }
        regen = null;
    }
}
```

I was expecting with a while loop for a smooth way for the slider to go down instead it just froze with me needing to go into taskmanager to close unity. I also tried putting a small wait for seconds hoping that it was a issue with lag.

Comment: The coroutine doesn't have problems. Try to attach the debugger and pause it while Unity is freezing, you may find out where the code hangs.

Comment: `I was expecting with a while loop for a smooth way for the slider to go down instead it just froze` .. looking at your code the `while` loops is responsible for the slider to go **UP** ... so maybe the issue is rather in how exactly `UseStamina` is called?

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, there's a couple of issues that I see.

Firstly, your stamina bar `value` should be a value between 0f and 1f. But your code has set a maxValue, which I'm not sure where that's coming from. So maybe you're using a different stamina bar? Not sure. But the default `Slider` uses a `value` between 0f and 1f.

Moving on to the second issue. You're doing divisions on integers. If you use any stamina, and your current stamina is less that the max stamina (which it almost always will be), then your code is always going to get stuck. For example, you use 1 stamina, then your calculation is 99 / 100 = 0. YHour current stamina will never be increased. That's just the way integer calculations work.

I also noted your `UseStamina` method reduces the stamina by the correct amount, but then your co-routine is trying to do modify the current stamina again. It's doing the caluclations twice, and only the first is the correct one.

You can cast to floats first, then back to an int. Or you could use a different measurement. For example:

```cs
public bool UseStamina ( int amount )
{
    if ( currentstamina - amount <= 0 )
    {
        Debug.Log ( "No enough stamina!" );
        return false;
    }

    if ( regen != null )
        StopCoroutine ( regen );

    currentstamina -= amount;
    regen = StartCoroutine ( regenstamina ( ) );

    return true;
}


private IEnumerator regenstamina ( )
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds ( 2 );
    var timer = 0f;
    while ( timer < 1f )
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        staminabar.value = Mathf.Lerp ( staminabar.value, ( float ) currentstamina / maxstamina, timer );
        yield return null;
    }
    regen = null;
}
```

Not that using `Lerp` like this is often seen as an error. You *generally* want set starting and ending points, but by having the starting point being updated to the current value, you end up with a bit of an 'easing' effect. Play around with that if the effect isn't what you're looking for.

Also note, the code was written but not tested... but, I stand by my previous comments.

Comment: `But the default Slider uses a value between 0f and 1f.` I think you confuse this with the [`normalizedValue`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-normalizedValue.html) .. having the [`minValue`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-minValue.html) and [`maxValue`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-maxValue.html) set correctly it is totally fine to set the [`value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-value.html) to an actual value

Comment: I think with the max stamina and `int` division OP was actually lucky ^^ `100/100` is `1` :D

Comment: @derHugo yes, I might be mistaken.  My initial thought was that value was 0-1… I’ll double check that. Still, his coroutine was still reliant on a `while` that was never going to be false and therefore loop forever.

Comment: but `while(currentstamina < maxstamina)` with `currentstamina += 1` would terminate at some point, wouldn't it? Anyway it is in a Coroutine wit a `yield return` within so it shouldn't freeze completely ..  Since the entire editor freezes I think the issue is not within this regen loop at all but rather in whatever attempts to call `UseStamina` repeatedly

Comment: @derHugo yeah, IF the OP tried to `UpdateStamina(0)`, then 100/100 = 1. But, if the value is anything other than 0, then 99/100 = 0 when doing integer calculations. So, while the coroutine isn’t “frozen”, the `while` statement will never exit.

Comment: No, OP has `currentstamina += maxstamina / 100` .. with `private int maxstamina = 100;` which is never changed (could as well be a `const`) => it will always be `100/100` => `1` .. and states they have to task-kill Unity so something seems to freeze entirely  ... not saying you wouldn't have good points .. but I think the core issue we don't even see yet

Comment: Yes the whole unity editor seemed to freeze thus needing me to task kill the unity editor. I have realised that 100/100 will be one and I have removed that unnecessary piece of code. I now understand that the slider uses float values and have changed that. I have taken account into your comments into consideration. I will rewrite a new system of code for this judging by the problems this script has caused me. I am planning on using this alot in my game and I dont want it to be a hassle to use. Thank you for your time.